# FBX not showing current version of mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, export, unity

I updated my mesh on an animated armature. When I export as FBX none of my changes appear to have been made. When I drag the blend file itself into Unity, the mesh appears perfect. I need to use FBX in Unity however due to diffusing materials, but the FBX is showing the old mesh. I've saved this FBX as a new file, not replacing the old. Any direction on what could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have saved the blend file, and I selected all objects and exported with that option ticked

Comment: Either Blender is possibly exporting some default pose or some different animation frame, or Unity is displaying or importing a different pose than what you expect to see.

Comment: Just figured what I did wrong! And you're on the right track Duarte... I had actually edited the mesh in a shape key rather than in basis. I realised this when I tried editing the blendshape in Unity. Rookie mistake, but may be helpful to someone with the same issue in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accidentally changed the mesh in a custom shape key rather than on the basis shape key - meaning the head enlarged when she blinked! I needed her head to be enlarged for every animation. For future reference, if you want to edit the mesh for all animations (shape keys), ensure you have basis shape key selected in object mode, then go into edit mode. As I had already made the mistake of editing another shape key, I just deleted it, edited the basis key as I should have done, and recreated the blinking shape key.